# Digital/electronic signature basic concepts and Example

Tags: .net, digital-signature, electronic-signature

I'm totally newbie on this area and I must do a little project with this. 
Can anyone tell me some links to get a basic example about how implement a simple digital signature. 
The project is very simple, create one web with a link where i must send a parameter called ticket(I don't know what this ticket is or how to create it)
and other web ASP.NET with a validator for that ticket. They gave me a dll library with validation methods, so It will make easier :D
I'm on the scare phase of the project :S

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

in your html you could try http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/. Depending on your jurisdiction there are some important rules about how to present and capture digital signature. You mentioned simple signature which is what this is, there are a number of different types of signature so i would just caution to take care about exactly what form of signature you need in case you need public/private key based methods instead.